# Memory usage problem with Kafka In-memory State store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, heap-memory, apache-kafka-streams

I used in-memory state store in stream application. I've 2 state store. Total data 3.3m count per state store. Total of 2 state store size 8,3gb. Partition count: 90. Replication Factor: 1. Broker size: 3. I have 10 instances for this stream, so 1 instance correspond 9 partitions.

[According to example scenario 3](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html), per instance used 830 mb ram. but this did not happen to me.

Problem:

The amount of memory used per instance is ~ 8.5 gb. Increasing over time and restarting instances. I used Processor API.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
Stores
    .keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(STATISTIC_HISTORICAL_DAILY_STORE),
            new EventKeySerde(),
            new EventSerde(Map.class, String.class, UtilizationValue.class))
    .withCachingEnabled()
    .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>()),
Stores
    .keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(STATISTIC_HISTORICAL_STORE),
            new EventKeySerde(),
            new EventSerde(Map.class, String.class, UtilizationValue.class))
    .withCachingEnabled()
    .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>())
```

---

```
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationProperties.getProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, defaultApplicationId));
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, defaultKeySerdeClassName);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, defaultValueSerdeClassName);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG), "all");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG), "gzip");

    // add from property files.
    "[max.poll.interval.ms]": 300000
    "[num.standby.replicas]": 1
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statisticHistoricalDailyStore = (KeyValueStore<EventKey, Event<Map<String, UtilizationValue>>>) context.getStateStore(STATISTIC_HISTORICAL_DAILY_STORE);
        this.statisticHistoricalStore = (KeyValueStore<EventKey, Event<Map<String, UtilizationValue>>>) context.getStateStore(STATISTIC_HISTORICAL_STORE);
        attributeDefinitions = loadAttributeDefinitions();

        context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, l -> {
            logger.info("Flush state stores...");
            this.statisticHistoricalDailyStore.flush();
            this.statisticHistoricalStore.flush();
        });
    }

   //In the process method, get and put operations are performed.
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm dealing with the same problem too. Anyone has a solition for this?

Comment: You don't really explain what you program does. Do you have a fixed key space? What computation are you doing? Do you ever delete any keys? Can you reduce (limit) you key space just for testing to see how much memory is used for this casE?